# Выгрузка контрагентов из 1С в пользователи Bitrix

Tags: битрикс, 1с

Возможно ли сделать выгрузку контрагентов из 1С в пользователи Bitrix?
В наличии

1С 8.3 УНФ редакция 1.6 на 1cfresh.

Сайт на 1С-Битрикс: Управление сайтом 21.500.0

Гуглил, вот что нашел:
https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=131&LESSON_ID=10205

Но тут версия 1С другая.
В УНФ найти не могу подобное, есть это:
[image: 1с]

Но контрагенты таким образом не выгружаются в пользователи сайта

Comment: а логины пароли вы им как собираетесь сделать?

Comment: Наверно в базе данных есть таблица с контрагентами. Программно через CUser::Add